# Theorem about positive matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-matrices

We will call a matrix *positive matrix* if all elements in the matrix are positive, and we will denote the *largest eigenvalue* with $\lambda_{\max}$, what is exist because of the [Perron–Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem).

**Theorem.** Let $A$ be a positive square matrix. If any element increases in the matrix then $\lambda_{\max}$ increases.

**My questions.**

1. Is there a name for this theorem and can anybody say books or papers what refer to it?
2. How to prove it?

Comment: It's easy to show if $A$ and the increased matrix $A'$ are symmetric: In that case, $\lambda_{\max}$ is then the operator norm $\|A\|$ and analogously for $A'$. The eigenvector $v$ belonging to $\lambda_{\max}$ has all $v_i > 0$, so $\|A'\| \geq \lambda_{\max} + ((A' - A)v, v) > \lambda_{\max}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*(Following Surb’s suggestion, the result in this answer is now strengthened.)*

This is just a simple consequence of Perron-Frobenius theorem. We can prove something slightly more general:

**Proposition.**<sup>[remark]</sup> Let $A,B$ be two nonnegative square matrices. If $A\le B$ entrywise, $A\ne B$ and $B$ is irreducible, then $\rho(A)<\rho(B)$.

**Proof.** Since $B$ is irreducible, $\rho(B)>0$. Let $(\rho(A),v)$ be a left Perron eigenpair of $A$. Observe that $v^T(B-A)\ne0$. This is obvious when $v$ is a positive vector. When $v$ has zero entries, $A$ must be reducible. So, by a permutation we may assume that $v^T=(v_1^T,0)$ for some positive vector $v_1$ of, say, length $m$. Since $v^T$ is a left eigenvector of $A$, $A$ must be block lower triangular when partitioned conformingly. Now, if $v^T(B-A)=(v_1^T,0)(B-A)=0$, the first $m$ rows of $B-A$ must be zero. But then $B-A$ and $B=(B-A)+A$ will be block lower triangular. This is impossible, as $B$ is irreducible. Therefore $v^T(B-A)\ne0$.

It follows that $v^T(B-A)$ is a nonnegative but nonzero vector.  Now let $(\rho(B),w)$ be a right Perron eigenpair of the $B$. Since $B$ is irreducible, $w$ is positive. Therefore
$$
\big(\rho(B)-\rho(A)\big)v^Tw = v^T(B-A)w >0
$$
and $\rho(B)>\rho(A)$.

**[Remark]** The result above is stated without proof as corollary 1.5 on p.27 of [*Nonnegative Matrices in the Mathematical Sciences*](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611971262) by Berman and Plemmons. Unlike in our formulation of the result, what the authors assume to be irreducible in the book is not $B$, but $A+B$. This is really strange, because when $0\le A\le B$, $B$ is irreducible if and only if $A+B$ is irreducible.

Comment: Note that your nice result can be slightly improved.

Answer (score 7):

For (almost) all positive vectors $x$, the [Power iterations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_method) do work, and we have $$\lambda_\max=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left(\|A^kx\|/\|x\|\right)^{1/k}$$ which shows that $\lambda_\max$ can not decrease as entries of $A$ increase. If $A'$ is obtained from $A$ by increasing *every* entry, we get $A'>(1+\varepsilon)A>A$, and your result follows.

Comment: Almost all? Can you/or someone else say a book or paper which write about this theorem?

Comment: You can find detailed proof of the following statement by the link from the answer. If $A$ is a complex matrix with Jordan basis $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ and eigenvalues satisfying $|\lambda_1|>|\lambda_i|$ for any $i\neq1$, then, any vector $b=c_1v_1+\ldots+c_nv_n$ with $c_1\neq0$ satisfies $v_1=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}b_t$ with $b_0=b$ and $b_{t+1}=\frac{Ab_t}{\|A b_t\|}$. From this we get $|\lambda_1|=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\left(\|A^tb\|/\|b\|\right)^{1/t}$ for almost all $b$.

Comment: In fact the user2097's proof works when $A>0,A'\geq A$. The condition $A>0$ is  necessary so that $\lambda_{max}$ is a simple eigenvalue. Let $||.||$ be a norm on  $\mathbb{R}^2$. I am not sure that $||[1,2]^T||\leq ||[1,3]^T||$. Thus, in order to show that $\rho(A')\geq \rho(A)$, it is better to choose a standard norm as $||.||_1$.

Answer (score 3):

I recently came across the following (beautiful) result which is slightly improving the answer of @user1551. The following results come from the book [Nonnegative Matrices in the Mathematical Sciences](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611971262) of Abraham Berman and Robert J. Plemmons:

> **Corollary 1.5 (p.27):**
>   Let $A,B$ be nonnegative square matrices.
>    - If $0\leq A \leq B$, then $\rho(A)\leq \rho(B)$.
>    - If $0\leq A \leq B$, $A\neq B$ and $A+B$ is irreducible, then $\rho(A)<\rho(B)$.

*Note 1:* Here $A\leq B$ means $A_{i,j}\leq B_{i,j}$ for every $i,j$.

*Note 2:* If $0\leq A \leq B$, $A\neq B$ and $A+B$ is reducible, then both can occur, i.e. $\rho(A)=\rho(B)$ or $\rho(A)<\rho(B)$. Indeed, let $U,V,W\in\Bbb R^{2\times 2}$ with
$$ U =\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad  V =\begin{pmatrix} 1& 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, 
\quad  W =\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Then $U\leq V \leq W$, $U\neq V$, $V\neq W$, $U+V$ is reducible, $V+W$ is reducible and $\rho(U)=\rho(V)<\rho(W)$.

*Note 3:* The following result shows that the answer of @user1551 is implied by Corollary 1.5.

> **Corollary 1.10 (p.28):**
>   Let $A,B$ be nonnegative square matrices. If $A$ is irreducible, then $A+B$ is irreducible.

Finally, to see how this also improves the answer to your question, note that the matrix $V$ above is reducible as well as the matrix $$V'=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ \epsilon & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$
However, Corollary 1.5 implies that $\rho(V)<\rho(V+V')$ be cause $V+V'$ is strictly positive (and thus irreducible).

Comment: It's nice to know the quoted results. +1

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for the reference. +1. Unfortunately the book doesn't contain an exact proof for "how is it a corollary", and also doesn't for the theorem above these corollarys. However there are analogous results related to cones with proofs.

Answer (score 2):

Your property follows easily the Collatz-Wieland formula, which is proved
on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Collatz.E2.80.93Wielandt_formula).
  In fact, that wikipedia page proves everything from scratch and provides references. So it should contain everything you're asking for.

How to deduce your property from the Collatz-Wieland formula : let $A=(a_{ij})$ and $B=(b_{ij})$ be two positive matrices, such that $a_{ij} \leq b_{ij}$ for every $i,j$. Define the Collatz-Wieland functions

$$
f_A(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=\min_{1\leq i\leq n,x_i\neq 0}\frac{\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j}{x_i}, \
f_B(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=\min_{1\leq i\leq n,x_i\neq 0}\frac{\sum_{j=1}^n b_{ij}x_j}{x_i}
$$

We deduce $f_A(x)\leq f_B(x)$ for every $x$, so the Perron root of $A$ is smaller than the Perron root of $B$, by the Collatz-Wieland formula.