# Submultiplicativity of Hadamard product for nonnegative

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hadamard-product

Let $A\in {\mathbb R}^{m\times n}_+$ be matrix with positive entries, and $B\in {\mathbb R}^{m\times n}$. Is it true:
$$
\sigma_1(A\circ B)\leq \max_{i,j}a_{ij} \cdot \sigma_1(B)
$$
In fact, I additionally have $A=[{\mathbf a}_1, \cdots, {\mathbf a}_n]$ and ${\mathbf a}_{i+1}\geq {\mathbf a}_{i}$ for $i=1,..,n-1$.

Comment: From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1848984/81360), the answer is no if we don't have your additional condition. If we add the condition, I suspect that the answer is still no but I'm not sure.