# Finding the $3 \times 3$ binary matrix with the least spectral radius greater than $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, discrete-optimization, spectral-radius

Let $A$ be a $3 \times 3$ matrix whose elements are only $0$ and $1$. Let $|\lambda_A^{\max}|$ be the [spectral radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius), i.e., the maximum absolute value of eigenvalues of $A$.

How can I choose the matrix $A$ such that $\log |\lambda_A^{\max}|$ has the minimal positive value?

Can someone give me a hint? Thank you!

Comment: There are only $2^9 = 512$ binary $3 \times 3$ matrices. Why not use brute force?

Comment: Are you serious? :D

Comment: @g.pomegranate sure, just use a computer

Comment: Any other limitations?  That seems awfully vague. The unit matrix gives you an easy upper bound on eigenvalue. Is 1 also a LOWER bound? That needs to be proved.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Is there a program that does it? or do I have to do one program? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran the following script on Matlab.  Some strange workarounds were necessary because my version is out of date.

```
Lmin = 3;
imin = 0;
Amin = zeros(3);

for i = 0:511
    b = dec2bin(i,9) == '1';
    A = reshape(b, [3,3]) + zeros(3);
    L = eigs(A,1);
    if L > 1.01 && L < Lmin
        Amin = A;
        Lmin = L;
        imin = i;
    end
end
```

The minimum is attained with
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&0&1\\1&0&1\\0&1&0}, \qquad \lambda_{max} \approx 1.3247
$$
I'm exploiting the fact that non-negative matrices always have a non-negative eigenvalue which coincides with the spectral radius.  We get the same even if we have `L = max(abs(eig(A)))`.

Comment: How about the unit matrix?

Comment: @DacianBonta the log of its spectral radius is not *positive*.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom so the solution is the unique real root of $f(\lambda) = \lambda^3 - \lambda - 1$, is there an algebraic argument as to why this should be so? (before we found the correct matrix)

Comment: I guess you have a pretty limited set of possible characteristic polynomials

Answer (score 4):

*(The other answer here has already addressed the OP's problem. We consider the general case below only for future reference.)*

For every $n\ge2$, denote by $\mathcal B_n$ the set of all nonzero $n\times n$ binary matrices. It is an easy consequence of Perron-Frobenius theorem that $\rho(A)\ge1$ if $A\in\mathcal B_n$ is irreducible. Let
\begin{align*}
r_n &= \min_{A\in\mathcal B_n,\ \rho(A)>1}\log\rho(A),\tag{1}\\
A_n &= \arg\min_{A\in\mathcal B_n,\ \rho(A)>1}\log\rho(A).\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Note that if $A$ is an irreducible nonnegative matrix and we increase the values of some of its entries, the spectral radius of the resulting matrix must strictly increase (see [Theorem about positive matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/907620) for proofs). Furthermore, if $A$ is also binary, it must contain a full-cycle graph, i.e. $A\ge P$ for some irreducible permutation matrix $P$. It follows that if $A_n$ is the minimiser in $(2)$, there are only two possibilities:

1. $A_n$ is reducible and hence $r_n=r_m$ for some $m<n$.
2. $A_n$ is obtained by flipping a zero entry of an irreducible permutation matrix to $1$.

Consequently, if we define

> $\rho_n:=$ the minimum possible spectral radius of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ obtained by flipping a zero entry of an irreducible permutation matrix to $1$,

then $r_n=\min(\rho_2,\rho_3,\ldots,\rho_n)$. We now prove that $\{\rho_n\}$ is actually a decreasing sequence and hence $r_n=\rho_n$.

**Proof.**

Let $A$ be a matrix obtained by flipping a zero entry of an irreducible permutation matrix $P$ to $1$, i.e. $A=P+E_{i_0j_0}$ for some $E_{i_0j_0}$ such that $j_0\ne\sigma(i_0)$, where $P$ corresponds to the full cycle $\sigma$. Recall that $\rho(A)>\rho(P)=1$.

Let $v$ be a Perron vector for $A$. By relabelling the rows and columns of $A$, we may assume without loss of generality that $0<v_1\le v_2\le\cdots\le v_n$. Since $\rho(A)v=Av=Pv+E_{i_0j_0}v$, we have
\begin{align*}
\rho(A)v_i &= v_{\sigma(i)}&\text{ if } i\ne i_0,\tag{3}\\
\rho(A)v_{i_0} &= v_{\sigma(i_0)}+v_{j_0}.\tag{4}
\end{align*}
It follows that $i_0=n$, otherwise by putting $i=n$ in $(3)$, we get $\rho(A)v_n = v_{\sigma(n)}\le v_n$, which is a contradiction because $\rho(A)>1$. Thus we may rewrite $(3)$ and $(4)$ as
\begin{align*}
\rho(A)v_i &= v_{\sigma(i)}&\text{ if } i<n,\tag{5}\\
\rho(A)v_n &= v_{\sigma(n)}+v_{j_0}.\tag{6}
\end{align*}
Thus it follows from $(5)$ that $\sigma(n-1)=n$, otherwise we would have
$\rho(A)v_{n-1}=v_k$ for some $k<n$, which is again a contradiction to $\rho(A)>1$. So, inductively, we have $\sigma(i)=i+1$ for $i=n-1,\,n-2,\ldots$ down to $1$ and in turn, $\sigma(n)$ must be equal to $1$. In other words,
\begin{align*}
\rho(A)v_i &= v_{i+1}&\text{ if } i<n,\tag{7}\\
\rho(A)v_n &= v_1+v_{j_0}.\tag{8}
\end{align*}
Hence by $(7)$, $v_i=\rho(A)^{i-1}v_1$ for every $i<n$, and by $(8)$, $\rho(A)^n = 1 + \rho(A)^{j_0}$ where $j_0<n$. It follows that $\rho(A)$ is a root to the polynomial equation
$$
f_{j_0}(x) := x^n - x^{j_0-1} - 1 = 0\tag{9}
$$
on the domain $x>1$. Since $f_{j_0}(x)$ is strictly increasing in $x$ but strictly decreasing in $j_0$, the root of $f_{j_0}$ is unique and it is minimised when $j_0$ is minimised, i.e. when $j_0=2$.

So, we conclude that $\rho_n$ is the positive root of $g_n(x):=x^n-x-1=0$ on $x>1$. As $g_n(x)$ is strictly increasing in both $x$ and $n$, we see that $\{\rho_n\}$ is a strictly decreasing sequence. Hence $r_n=\rho_n$.

In short, for every $n\ge2$, the global minimiser $A_n$ of $r_n$, up to permutation similarity, is uniquely given by the companion matrix of $x^n-x-1$, i.e.
$$
A_n=\pmatrix{0&1\\ \vdots&&\ddots\\ \vdots&&&\ddots\\ 0&&&&1\\ 1&\color{red}{1}&0&\cdots&0},
$$
and $\rho(A_n)$ is the unique positive root of $x^n-x-1=0$ on $x>1$.

Comment: Really a fantastic answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as it

# generate all binary words of length 9
allwords = list(it.product(*([(0,1)] * 9)))

# convert binary words to NumPy arrays
allarrays = map(np.asarray, allwords)

# convert 1D arrays to 2D arrays
allmatrices = []
for a in allarrays:
    allmatrices.append(a.reshape(3,3))

# compute spectral radii
results = []
for m in allmatrices:
    spectrum = np.linalg.eigvals(m)     # spectrum of matrix
    spectrad = max(abs(spectrum))       # spectral radius
    results.append((m, spectrad))

# filter pairs with spectral radius greater than 1
adresults = filter(lambda (m,s) : s>1.000001, results)

# print admissible results
print sorted(adresults, key=lambda t: t[1])
```

produces the following list:

```
[(array([[0, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 1.3247179572447454), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.3247179572447454), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.3247179572447461), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.3247179572447461), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.3247179572447463), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 1.3247179572447469), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.4142135623730951), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.4142135623730951), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 1.4142135623730951), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.4655712318767682), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 1.4655712318767682), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 1.4655712318767684), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.4655712318767684), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 1.4655712318767684), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 1.4655712318767684), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498942), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498942), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498942), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498945), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498945), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 1.6180339887498945), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498947), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498947), (array([[0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 1]]), 1.6180339887498949), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 1.6180339887498951), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 1.6180339887498951), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.6180339887498951), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 1.6180339887498951), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 1.7548776662466905), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 1.7548776662466905), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 1.7548776662466923), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 1.7548776662466923), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.7548776662466952), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 1.7548776662466952), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.8019377358048385), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 1.8019377358048385), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 1.8019377358048387), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.8019377358048387), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.8019377358048387), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 1.8019377358048401), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.8392867552141596), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 1.8392867552141601), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.8392867552141601), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.839286755214161), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 1.839286755214161), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 1.839286755214161), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 1.839286755214161), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.839286755214161), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 1.8392867552141612), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.8392867552141612), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 1.8392867552141614), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 1.8392867552141614), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 1.9999999999999982), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 1.9999999999999987), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 1.9999999999999993), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 1.9999999999999993), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.9999999999999993), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.9999999999999993), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.9999999999999993), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 1.9999999999999996), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.9999999999999996), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.9999999999999996), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.9999999999999996), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 1.9999999999999996), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.9999999999999996), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 1.9999999999999996), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 1.9999999999999996), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 1.9999999999999998), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 1.9999999999999998), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 1.9999999999999998), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 1.9999999999999998), (array([[0, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[0, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[0, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[0, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 2.0), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 0]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 0]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0]]), 2.0), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 1]]), 2.0), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 2.0000000000000004), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 2.0000000000000004), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 2.0000000000000004), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 2.0000000000000009), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 2.0000000000000009), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.0000000000000013), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.1478990357047865), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 2.1478990357047865), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 2.1478990357047869), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 2.1478990357047874), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 2.1478990357047882), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.1478990357047891), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.2055694304005882), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 2.2055694304005882), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 2.2055694304005886), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 2.2055694304005886), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 2.2055694304005904), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.2055694304005904), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 2.2469796037174663), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 2.2469796037174663), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 2.2469796037174663), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.2469796037174667), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 2.2469796037174667), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.2469796037174667), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 2.2469796037174667), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.2469796037174667), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 2.2469796037174667), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.2469796037174672), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 2.2469796037174676), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 2.2469796037174676), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.3247179572447445), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 2.3247179572447445), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 2.3247179572447454), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 2.3247179572447454), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 2.3247179572447458), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.3247179572447458), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 2.4142135623730931), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 2.4142135623730931), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.4142135623730936), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.414213562373094), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 2.414213562373094), (array([[0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.4142135623730945), (array([[0, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.4142135623730945), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.4142135623730945), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 2.4142135623730945), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 2.4142135623730949), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 2.4142135623730949), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 2.4142135623730949), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 2.4142135623730949), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0]]), 2.4142135623730949), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.4142135623730954), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.4142135623730954), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 0]]), 2.4142135623730954), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.4142135623730958), (array([[1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.6180339887498945), (array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.6180339887498945), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.6180339887498953), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1]]), 2.6180339887498953), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.6180339887498962), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1]]), 2.6180339887498962), (array([[0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.7320508075688772), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0]]), 2.7320508075688772), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 2.7320508075688776), (array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]), 3.0)]
```

Thus, the minimal admissible spectral radius is

$$\bar{\rho} \approx \color{blue}{1.324718}$$

and $3! = 6$ matrices have this spectral radius, namely,

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \qquad\qquad\qquad \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \qquad\qquad\qquad \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \qquad\qquad\qquad \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$