# Spectral radius of a stochastic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-matrices

Let P be a irreducible stochastic matrix and Q be a matrix obtained by making one positive entry of P to be zero and remaining terms are same as P. If 1,t are the largest and second largest positive eigenvalues of P and s is the largest eigenvalue (spectral radius) of Q, is it true that t ≤ s < 1?

Comment: Your question doesn’t make sense because $t$ can be non-real.

Comment: We assume that P has a positive real eigenvalue other than 1.

Comment: So, if the eigenvalues of $P$ are $1,\,\pm0.9i$ and $0.8$, do you mean the ”second largest” eigenvalue of $P$ is $0.8$?

Comment: Yes,it is the second largest among the positive eigenvalues, assuming there is at least one less than 1.

Comment: It is true that $\rho(Q)<1$, for the reason described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/924257).

Comment: Yeah, do we know anything about the other inequality?